# axios request not going through to backend

Tags: axios, react-router

I'm struggling getting this axios call to work.  It's in a password reset feature, and it calls an axios request that sends through to the back end, but it's just coming up with an error instead of executing the code in the router route.

I call the request in this block here.

front end side:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
const {
  match: {
    params: { token },
  },
} = this.props;
try {
  const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/users/reset', {
    params: {
      resetPasswordToken: token,
    },
  });
  console.log(response)
  if (response.data.message === 'password reset link a-ok') {
    this.setState({
      username: response.data.username,
      updated: false,
      isLoading: false,
      error: false,
    });
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.response.data);
  this.setState({
    updated: false,
    isLoading: false,
    error: true,
  });
}
}
```

It's getting the proper token and everything, but the http://localhost:5000/api/users/reset should be pointing to the /reset route in the code below, and it's never reached.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const keys = require("../../config/keys");

const validateRegisterInput = require("../../validation/register");
const validateLoginInput = require("../../validation/login");
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const crypto = require('crypto');

require('dotenv').config();

const User = require("../../models/User");

router.route('/reset').get((req, res, next) => {
  User.find({
    where: {resetPasswordToken: req.query.resetPasswordToken,
    resetPasswordExpires: {
      $gt: Date.now(),
    },
  },
}).then(user => {
  if(user == null) {
    console.log('password reset link is invalid or has expired');
    res.json('password reset link is invalid or has expired');
  }else{
    res.status(200).send({
      username: user.username,
      message: 'password reset link a-ok',
        });
      }
    });
  });

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Could you add the full routing code and the error it gives?

Comment: Oh whoops!  I guess the error would be helpful haha.  

Error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "reset" at path "_id" for model "users"

And the full routing is basically there.  There's lots of other routes in the users.js file that contains all the routes, but they're all individually working, just this one won't for whatever reason.

Comment: The only thing that's not another route is the stuff at the top.  I'll add it to the original question. Thank you @TamasSzoke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually @TamasSzoke you led me to answer my own question so I thank you!  I had another route that was just /:id and that's what it was trying to validate there.

Just have to change that one up and it'll be all good.

thank you!!!

Comment: I'm glad my question helped, you can mark this answer as accepted.